# Visual Studio disable opening generated views (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Does anyone know if it's possible to disable the views that load into the main perspective after you generate a controller with read/write access using Entity Framework?

It becomes a pain to keep closing the tabs manually.

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you mean the page that opens when you start debugging the solution?

Comment: negative. I mean the Views that load into Visual Studios in the tabs. Create.cshtml, Details.cshtml, Edit.cshtml, Delete.cshtml...